# Changing chart properties, ArcMap 10.3 Desktop

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.3, timeslider

I am attempting to change the properties of the attached chart to create something a little more aesthetic. After searching ESRI Help, message boards, google... I have not found any material on how to make these charts look better (I can't even find a way to change the font!).

Usually, I would just make the chart in MS Excel, however this chart will be part of a time series and needs to be linked to the data to update as time moves, so it cannot be static.

Do you know of any way to change these properties without unlinking it from my dataset?

[image: A Boring ESRI Chart]

Comment: Right click on the chart. Click on advanced properties. You can adjust just about every aspect of the chart.

Comment: That worked. I was unable to see the "Advanced Properties" because I had already added the chart to layout. Note to anyone else: set all of the design properties in the chart pop-up window before clicking "add to layout" or else you will have to create the chart again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your graph colors are generally based off of your layer's symbology.  Once you have created your graph you can right click it and hit advanced properties in order to change font and colors.  Also see this link for more help:  [http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/map/graphs/properties-of-graphs.html](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/map/graphs/properties-of-graphs.htm)